# How to select just the lowest sum total in a GROUP BY query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question related to SQL. I have a dataset, which contains 2 columns, tasker_ID and the working_hours.

The columns looks likes this way:

```
tasker_id   working_hours  
   1            30
   2 .          20
   3            14
   1            23
   4            24
   2            39
   3            27
   2            18
   5            0
```

...
And I want to find out which tasker has been worked the least? (We will not count people who worked 0 hours totally)

At first, I used such code to achieve this:

```
select tasker_id, sum(working_hours) as sum_hours
from test.test
group by tasker_id
having sum_hours>0
order by sum_hours;
```

From the order, I can easily see which IDs has the least working hours, but I want to use Min function to **only** show which ID has the least working hours.

And here is my SQL code:

```
select tasker_id, min(sum_worked) as min_worked from (
select tasker_id, sum(working_hours) as sum_worked
from test.test
group by tasker_id
having sum_worked>0)a
;
```

But the code seems wrong, can someone guide me on this? I knew the the value function goes in a group way, but i do not know where I got wrong. Or can someone show directly the right code?

PS: I am using MySQL.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) ?

Comment: Without a demonstration of why these queries do not work (i.e. why the output differs from what you expect) this is a bit harder to answer. Since the question also appears to be abandoned, I am voting to close. We need an [mcve] here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `where` in internal query. You are referring to `sum_worked` in where clause which is not correct as `where` is executed before `select`. Instead use `having`.

```
select tasker_id, min(sum_worked) as min_worked 
from (
     select tasker_id, sum(working_hours) as sum_worked
     from test.test
     group by tasker_id
     having sum_worked>0
     ) a;
```

Comment: Hi, I modified the codes, but it still has some errors. It seems that it is not where or having problems.

Answer (score 0):

sum_worked is not defined in the table that’s why he cannot find it, because you used where condition.
You need to replace the where condition with “having sum_worked>0” and to be after the group by statement.

Or you can move the same where condition to be in the outer query

Answer (score 0):

If you have analytic functions available you can try:

```
SELECT tasker_id, sum_worked
FROM
(
    SELECT
        tasker_id, SUM(working_hours) AS sum_worked,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(working_hours)) rn
    FROM test.test
    GROUP BY tasker_id
    HAVING sum_worked > 0
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Should there be a tie for lowest number of hours worked, and you wanted all ties, you could replace `ROW_NUMBER` with a rank function.

On databases which support a limit statement, and assuming we only want the first lowest tasker, we can simplify this to:

```
SELECT
    tasker_id, SUM(working_hours) AS sum_worked
FROM test.test
GROUP BY tasker_id
HAVING sum_worked > 0
ORDER BY sum_worked
LIMIT 1;     -- works on MySQL and Postgres
```

Comment: I knew what you concerned, what I want is to use min function to select the minimum working hours and its ID, but what I got is every ID's minimum working hours. And that confused me.

Comment: Thanks! But my major concern is about the subqueries of Min function. How can I get it right? I tried a way, and the results were not  only for the minimum hours cases for that ID. If I add group by statement, it shows all of the IDs minimum hours, which is wired.

Comment: I can't help you because I have no idea to which code you are referring.  There are several valid answers here, I recommend trying one and seeing how it goes.